# Graph nomenclature for class-grouped vertices and edges

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a name for the subset of graph theory dealing with vertices and edges of distinct classes? For example, I could have a graph in which each vertex must be either blue, yellow or red and each vertex must be either dashed or solid.

I'm working on a problem with these characteristics but I have no background in graph theory. This makes it hard to find the right terminology to search to find solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminology can vary, but it is usual to talk about a *[labelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_labeling)* of a graph for the most general case. Although labels can be text strings, they are usually numbers.

These labels can also be referred to as *[colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)* although this usually has a more precise meaning. For example, from the graph coloring wikipedia:

> When used without any qualification, a coloring of a graph is almost always a proper vertex coloring, namely a labelling of the graph’s vertices with colors such that no two vertices sharing the same edge have the same color.

This is more restrictive than just assigning {'yellow', 'red', 'blue'} to the vertices. There is a lot of literature out there about such proper colorings, so be aware when searching.

Finally, the process of assigning labels to vertices is referred to as *partition* - although again, many people are interested in partitions with particular properties, and not arbitrary partitions.

Comment: Thanks! The graph labeling wiki you linked suggests that the common form is to use distinct labels. Are non-distinct labels, as in my example, an uncommon problem without as much study? Or is there a better name to google them by?

Comment: Ok, so one way to think about it is that a labelling is a kind of coloring where each color is unique. I have found that problems involving 'improper' colorings are less common. (For my use-case it is chemical graphs where colors are elements.) Unfortunately, the case of assigning arbitrary colors to vertices and edges has less structure so tends to be studied less?

Comment: Oh hey, I'm also looking at chemical graphs! I'm surprised this isn't something more commonly studied. Do you have any other resources you find useful for these problems that I might check out?

Comment: Argh! Also, it looks like ther term 'improper coloring' is used in various ways to mean "not a proper colouring, but has some restriction on the coloring". Sigh. Sorry, I've no idea what it might be called

Comment: Oh! Well, it depends on what you want to do. There is quite a lot of work on graph canonicalization for chemicals (eg InChI) or substructure matching, or reaction atom-atom mapping. That might be a better question for chemistry stack exchange - or biostar perhaps?